# Taking screenshot of the viewport only (Firefox and IE), not the whole page, using Selenium Webdriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browserstack

I'm using Selenium Webdriver automated testing on Browserstack and when I take a screenshot on Firefox and IE, it takes the screenshot of the whole page. But as my page contains a very long list - the screenshot is too 'long' and because of that it's not a clear image and it's difficult to see if the page behaves the right way. I need it to do exact as the Chrome does: the screenshot of the viewport width and height only. Is it possible on Firefox and IE?

The code I use:

```
Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
ss.SaveAsFile(imageSave, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: you can always take a ss using the Windows built in one and crop it

Comment: You can use crop the screenshot and save to new file

Comment: Tnx guys. Do I have to crop it manually? It's a plenty of images - that's impossible. Is there a way to make it automatic?  @Steve

Comment: @buca yea, you can use Windows API to get the window's position and size, then you can just crop it using code based on the position/size

Comment: @Steve tnx I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to `Selenium 3` version.

In `Selenium 2.*` versions, complete web page is taken as screenshot.

From `Selenium 3.*` version, **only visible portion** of the web page is taken as screenshot.

So, just upgrading the selenium version, you can achieve the behaviour, and the same code should work.

From [Selenium official docs](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#taking-a-screenshot):

```
Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)webDriver).GetScreenshot();
string screenshot = ss.AsBase64EncodedString;
byte[] screenshotAsByteArray = ss.AsByteArray;
ss.SaveAsFile(activeDir + TestSuiteName + "//" + FileNanme + imageFormat, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

---

I validated this behaviour in `Python` with `Selenium 3.0.2` in both `Chrome & Firefox`

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/users/2575259/naveen')
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('D:/Naveen/so/google.png') 
driver.quit()
```

Comment: That's not the case with Safari and IE